# build a semantic map-knowrob

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, semantics, ros

I'm having some problems with the rospackage knowrob_gui knowrobGUI.
I need it to build a semantic map that i have to integrate with my owl file.I started following this guide:
But when i run the command:`rosrun knowrob_gui KnowRobGUI`
i have this problem i thing about java version:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/ros/node/NodeMain : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at org.knowrob.prolog.PrologInterface.initJPLProlog(PrologInterface.java:70)
at org.knowrob.gui.KnowRobGuiMain.setup(KnowRobGuiMain.java:66)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

the result of command java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

the result of command javac -version:

javac 1.7.0_80

File KnowRobGUI:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(uname -i) == 'x86_64' ]; then
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH    
else
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
export LD_PRELOAD=libswipl.so
export SWI_HOME_DIR=/usr/lib/swi-prolog
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
GUI_PATH=`rospack find knowrob_gui`
${GUI_PATH}/knowrob_gui/build/install/knowrob_gui/bin/knowrob_gui
```

How i can solve it?

Comment: What is the code that results in this?

Comment: This is really not readable, add it to your question.